# JVM low-memory tuning

Tags: debian, performance, java, virtual-memory

What command-line **options** would provide the **lowest memory-footprint** JVM, in OpenJDK, or possibly other JVMs (Linux/Debian)? I'm willing to disable JIT, live with slow or choppy garbage collection, whatever, as long as I can reduce the memory footprint.

I've tried searching but up-to-date Java tuning information seems to be incredibly difficult to come by. And JamVM appears dead.